# Conda installing wrong version of openjdk

Tags: conda, java-17

I am trying to install the OpenJDK 17 in a Conda enviroment but I only get older versions.

When I create a new enviroment with `python=3.10` and then run the command to install the Java OpenJDK version 17 like this:

`conda install -c conda-forge openjdk` (source: [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openjdk))

it only installs a version `1.8.0_332`.

I am trying to do this on a server I am not in control of that already has an older Java version installed. Though, I thought that this would not matter. See Image for the steps:

[image: console output]

Answer (score 0):

The fix is pretty weird to me.

- create a new enviroment with `conda create myEnv` without the python=3.10 parameter so that in my case the starting version of python was 2.7.5
- then activate the enviroment and run `conda install -c conda-forge openjdk` which now gives the correct version of the openjdk for some reason
- to fix the python version I ran `conda install python=3.10` so that I have both things at the same time

I conclude that it is super weird that the installation order here matters.

**Note:** Locally the approach on the in the question on Windows 10 works but not when I try to do it on a Linux Server. There only the answer approach works.